# resin getRemoteAddr() always throw NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, resin

Linux web server with nginx + resin4.0 pro, always throw error like this:

```
{http://*:8082-117} java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.caucho.server.http.HttpServletRequestImpl.getRemoteAddr(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:921)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:119)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:96)
    at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletFilterChain.doFilter(ServletFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
    at com.caucho.server.cache.ProxyCacheFilterChain.doRequestCacheable(ProxyCacheFilterChain.java:245)
    at com.caucho.server.cache.ProxyCacheFilterChain.doFilter(ProxyCacheFilterChain.java:188)
    at com.caucho.server.webapp.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:156)
    at com.caucho.server.webapp.AccessLogFilterChain.doFilter(AccessLogFilterChain.java:95)
    at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletInvocation.service(ServletInvocation.java:287)
    at com.caucho.server.http.HttpRequest.handleRequest(HttpRequest.java:792)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.dispatchRequest(TcpSocketLink.java:730)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequest(TcpSocketLink.java:689)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequestsImpl(TcpSocketLink.java:669)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequests(TcpSocketLink.java:617)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.AcceptTask.doTask(AcceptTask.java:104)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.ConnectionReadTask.runThread(ConnectionReadTask.java:98)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.ConnectionReadTask.run(ConnectionReadTask.java:81)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.AcceptTask.run(AcceptTask.java:67)
    at com.caucho.env.thread.ResinThread.runTasks(ResinThread.java:164)
    at com.caucho.env.thread.ResinThread.run(ResinThread.java:130)
```

Comment: Can you comment some details more? e.g. what situation perhaps cause this error.

Comment: Occur once every few minutes when request website，I don't know why.

Comment: Web site can be a normal visit, just log on every so often thrown.

Answer (score 0):

It may cause by older resin.jar. The code:

```
    public String getRemoteAddr(){return _request.getRemoteAddr();}
```

This code is updated on 16 Jun 2012 and became:

```
    public String getRemoteAddr(){AbstractHttpRequest request = _request;   return request != null ? request.getRemoteAddr() : null;}
```